# Tilemill taking a long time to export to mbtiles

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

I have a map with a lot of points (60k). They're spread across 21 separate layers. (It's a demographic scatterplot map.)

I'm exporting to mbtiles with a zoom range of 11-15. The geographic area is around 700 square miles.

I'm only exporting the points, not any underlying basemap. Supposedly, this should only generate a 1-10mb file. But I'm getting a half-hour wait to bake the tiles.

Is that unusual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

30 minute TileMill exports can be on the fast side depending on the size/type of project, but in your case there's probably ways to optimize this much further.

The most important factor is to make sure your data is properly indexed:

- For Shapefiles, use the `shapeindex` command-line utility. (On Ubuntu this is provided by the `mapnik-utils` package. I'm not sure about other platforms but it may be included with TileMill already.)
- For PostGIS tables, make sure there is an index on the geometry column with the `USING gist` option.
- SQLite files will be automatically indexed by TileMill.
- GeoJSON files cannot be indexed and should be converted to another format for best performance.

Having everything already projected to Web Mercator (`EPSG:3857`) is a good idea too. TileMill is also reasonably well-optimized for `EPSG:4326`.

Finally you may want to tweak your buffer and metatile settings, however for a smaller project like this it may not make much difference. If you are only exporting points (without labels) your buffer only needs to be as wide as your largest marker-width (the default buffer-size is 128 pixels). See [this guide](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/metatiles/) for more information about when and how to adjust buffers and metatiles.